# Space in border top

Tags: html, css

When I add border to my video, it doesn't appear correct on top. There is some space. How can I delete it?

```css
.video-content {
    border: 10px solid #2f2f2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-content">
      <video src="video/Portfolio-landing.mov" controls></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: You'll have to show an example that replicates the error. There's no way to tell what the problem is based only on the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you didn't set `margin` and `padding` in the body. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would margin and padding on the body have any effect on the border of other elements?

Comment: @JJJ I couldn't see the image before and I thought that something like this may be causing it. Now I'm sure it cannot be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;` for the `div` something like below. It will work fine

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="video-content">   
        <video class="fullscreen-bg__video" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" controls></video>
</div>
```

.video-content {
        border: 10px solid #2f2f2f;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }

Answer (score -1):

Making the video element `display: block` will probably fix the problem

```
.video-content video {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Anna Well... maybe if you provided some _useful_ details, we could get somewhere.  As of right now, your code in your question is useless.  It doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to add CSS reset rules if you don't want such unwanted behaviours.

```css
*{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px
 }

.video-content {
    border: 10px solid #2f2f2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-content">
      <video src="video/Portfolio-landing.mov" controls></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... perhaps it happens because of bootstrap.css

Comment: Your browser also adds some default padding, margin and other values to elements. For that CSS reset is important. But downvote?

Comment: Guess what. When people can't help you, thats what they do. Anyways hope you found your solution.

Comment: I found solution in bootstrap css. Thank you.

Comment: Pleasure..Cheers!!

Comment: Down-voted for use of `0px`. Any decent IDE will let you know units are bloat in this case.

Comment: But you cant expect everyone to use IDE for developing stuffs like these. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Actually, I do. If you don't use an IDE, you shouldn't be providing answers and advice to others on SO, from my point of view. But I did not need to run your answer through an IDE to know you are not using one. And by not using an IDE, you are not constantly receiving information regarding common errors in your code and therefore are likely to pass those errors to others through your answers.

Comment: Calm down dude. Its entirely upon the requirement of the project whether you want to use an IDE or not. I have worked with `Eclipse`,`NetBeans`,`VisualStudio` and know thier advantages. But its simply an overkill to use these to develop sites like mentioned above. And don't expect everone to work the way you work. For more reference read this article on `IDE vs text editors`:www.makeuseof.com/tag/text-editors-vs-ides-one-better-programmers/ , this will make your understanding more clear as to when to when not use `IDEs`:   @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: I am very calm and relaxed. :) But this doesn't relax the standards by which I appreciate quality of code, be it mine or other's. I chose to tell you the reason for which I down-voted with the sincere hope it might be helpful. To you. Also, please note the **"from my point of view"** expression in my previous comment. Have a great day!

Comment: Your comment is against each and every one of those who don't use IDEs for such things. You might be an expert in IDE but that doesn't mean that text editors are obsolete. And its completely irrational to say `If you don't use an IDE, you shouldn't be providing answers and advice to others on SO, from my point of view` coz there are people out there who might be using text editors and are not bothered bout using IDEs. You too have a calm day!!!@AndreiGheorghiu